# How does Pig determine which python to use in running python streaming?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I have multiple different python versions in my laptop and I set up a single node hadoop. Now I am running a pig script (0.12.1) which calls a python streaming script (using REGISTER). How can I control which python version to use? If it is not controllable, which python will be picked up?

Comment: When I printed out sys.path and sys.version inside my Python script, I got the followings: /Library/Python/2.7/... and 2.7.5

Comment: If I just type "python --version" in my commandline, I got version 2.7.8

Comment: You need to use `jython`